# c# parameter implicit conversion

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

Having this code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Check(3);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Check(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am an int");
        }

        static void Check(long i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a long");
        }

        static void Check(byte i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a byte");
        }    
    }
```

Why this code prints "I am an int" and not "I am a long" ?

Comment: Try `Check(3L)`.  The L indicates to the compiler that you want the literal to be a `long` instead of an `int`

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Method Resolution, long vs int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125585/c-sharp-method-resolution-long-vs-int)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why this code prints "I am an int" and not "I am a long" ?

Because the compiler goes through the rules of overload resolution, which are in the C# 5 spec, starting at section 7.5.3.

Both of those are *applicable function members* (i.e. they'd both be valid for the argument list) but the `Check(int)` method is "better" than the `Check(long)` method (section 7.5.3.2) because the type of the argument is `int`, and an identity conversion is "better" than a widening conversion (section 7.5.3.3).

> Given an implicit conversion C1 that converts from an expression E to a type T1, and an implicit conversion C2 that converts from an expression E to a type T2, C1 is a better conversion than C2 if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - E has a type S and an identity conversion exists from S to T1 but not from S to T2
> - ...

Here `E` is `int`, `T1` is `int`, and `T2` is `long`. There's an identity conversion from `int` to `int`, but not from `int` to `long`... therefore this rule applies, and the conversion from `int` to `int` is better than the conversion from `int` to `long`.

Comment: Hi Jon, I've updated my code and I've added another Check method with byte parameter, but the code prints again "I am an int". why 3 is considered an int and not a byte?

Comment: and where can I find these rules on MSDN site?

Comment: @BudaGavril: I wouldn't use MSDN - I'd download the complete specification: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029

Comment: can you please explain me what does identity conversion means? Here is what I've found on msdn :?An identity conversion converts from any type to the same type. This conversion exists only such that an entity that already has a required type can be said to be convertible to that type." but it's still not very clear for me

Comment: @Buda: As it says - it's a conversion from a type to itself... In this case from int to int.

Comment: but why couldn't be from byte to byte? Why is that special int type?

Comment: @Buda: Because the type of the literal 3 is int. Again, check the spec.