# How does the compiler choose which method to call when the input specified can be used to call more than one functions

Tags: c#

I tried the below code

```
class Sample
{
    public void Display(int a, float b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("value of a = " + a);
        Console.WriteLine("value of b = " + b);
    }
    public void Display(float a, float b)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("value of a = " + a);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Operation obj2 = new Operation();
       obj2.Display(5, 5);
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
value of a = 5
value of b = 5
```

How does C# compiler know which function to call??

However if the method signatures were

```
public void Display(int a, float b)

public void Display(float a, int b)
```

I get a compile time error saying `Call is ambiguous`. How is it that the compiler is now unable to differentiate?

Comment: Operation obj2 = new Operation(); the Operation here is the `Sample` class?

Comment: I already edited it, but its broken again

Comment: @YogitaKudva, i dont know why you will not accept the edit, your just complicating things, welcome to SO!

Comment: @Desperado : Sorry, made the change. I was working with 2 different classes so wrote the wrong class name. I made the change now

Comment: Sorry, new to posting questions to SO. So learning to add code and trying to make it presentable

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413926/method-overloading-in-c-sharp-and-java

Comment: This is a question about 'Method Resolution Order' that should be enough to find your answers from google.  This is one potential starting place: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is [how method overload resolution works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx). According to the C# language specification, the rule to find [the best method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338(v=vs.71).aspx) is:

> Given an argument list A with a set of argument types {A1, A2, ...,
> AN} and two applicable function members MP and MQ with parameter types
> {P1, P2, ..., PN} and {Q1, Q2, ..., QN}, MP is defined to be a better
> function member than MQ if
>
> - for each argument, the implicit conversion
>   from AX to PX is not worse than the implicit conversion from AX to QX,
>   and
> - for at least one argument, the conversion from AX to PX is better
>   than the conversion from AX to QX.
>
> When performing this evaluation, if
> MP or MQ is applicable in its expanded form, then PX or QX refers to a
> parameter in the expanded form of the parameter list.

**Update**

The above explanation is from the VS. NET 2003 specification, and should be considered outdated. The C# speficiation for VS 2015 can be found in the installation folder of VS 2015, at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Specifications\1033`

The specification for the "better function member" reads at follows:

> **7.5.3.2 Better function member**
>
> For the purposes of determining the better function member, a
> stripped-down argument list A is constructed
> containing just the argument expressions themselves in the order they
> appear in the original argument list.
>
> Parameter lists for each of the
> candidate function members are constructed in the following way:
>
> - The expanded form is used if the function member was applicable only
>   in the expanded form.
> - Optional parameters with no corresponding
>   arguments are removed from the parameter list
> - The parameters are
>   reordered so that they occur at the same position as the corresponding
>   argument in the argument list.
>
> Given an argument list A with a set of
> argument expressions { E1, E2, ..., EN } and two applicable function
> members MP and MQ with parameter types { P1, P2, ..., PN } and { Q1,
> Q2, ..., QN }, MP is defined to be a better function member than MQ if
>
> - for each argument, the implicit conversion from EX to QX is not
>   better than the implicit conversion from EX to PX, and
> - for at least
>   one argument, the conversion from EX to PX is better than the
>   conversion from EX to QX.
>
> When performing this evaluation, if MP or MQ
> is applicable in its expanded form, then PX or QX refers to a
> parameter in the expanded form of the parameter list.
>
> In case the
> parameter type sequences {P1, P2, …, PN} and {Q1, Q2, …, QN} are
> equivalent (i.e. each Pi has an identity conversion to the
> corresponding Qi), the following tie-breaking rules are applied, in
> order, to determine the better function member.
>
> - If MP is a
>   non-generic method and MQ is a generic method, then MP is better than
>   MQ.
> - Otherwise, if MP is applicable in its normal form and MQ has a
>   params array and is applicable only in its expanded form, then MP is
>   better than MQ.
> - Otherwise, if MP has more declared parameters than
>   MQ, then MP is better than MQ. This can occur if both methods have
>   params arrays and are applicable only in their expanded forms.
> - Otherwise if all parameters of MP have a corresponding argument
>   whereas default arguments need to be substituted for at least one
>   optional parameter in MQ then MP is better than MQ.
> - Otherwise, if
>   MP has more specific parameter types than MQ, then MP is better than
>   MQ. Let {R1, R2, …, RN} and {S1, S2, …, SN} represent the
>   uninstantiated and unexpanded parameter types of MP and MQ. MP’s
>   parameter types are more specific than MQ’s if, for each parameter, RX
>   is not less specific than SX, and, for at least one parameter, RX is
>   more specific than SX:
>
>   - A type parameter is less specific than a
>     non-type parameter.
>   - Recursively, a constructed type is more specific
>     than another constructed type (with the same number of type arguments)
>     if at least one type argument is more specific and no type argument is
>     less specific than the corresponding type argument in the other.
>   - An
>     array type is more specific than another array type (with the same
>     number of dimensions) if the element type of the first is more
>     specific than the element type of the second.
> - Otherwise if one
>   member is a non-lifted operator and  the other is a lifted operator,
>   the non-lifted one is better.
> - Otherwise, neither function member is
>   better.

Another good source is the [explanation on C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) by Jon Skeet.